# vCenter 6.7 error while creating new users (Single Sign On)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

i'm running a vCenter Server Appliance with Embedded Platform Services Controller version 6.7.0.140000

I'm trying to create a new user to allow using the vSphere web console to a specified VM only

While trying to reach the Users and Groups page (Home > Administration > Single Sign On > Users and Groups), i found this error:

"Unexpected error encountered while performinig your action."

the vcenter is a fresh new installation, no upgrade from previous version was done

any ideas ?

greetings

Comment: What did VMware say when you logged the case with them?

Comment: Maybe you can't reach the domain. Is this helpful:? https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2048177?lang=en_US

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?